# Why Advanced AJAX Product Filters for Woocommerce update page?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, filter, woocommerce

When I apply filters store page is updated. 
There are errors on the page:

```
Uncaught TypeError: e.indexOf is not a function
at w.fn.init.w.fn.load (jquery-3.3.1.min.js?ver=5.1:2)
at Scrollbar.concat.min.js?ver=1.3.0.2:5
at Scrollbar.concat.min.js?ver=1.3.0.2:4
at Scrollbar.concat.min.js?ver=1.3.0.2:4
at Scrollbar.concat.min.js?ver=1.3.0.2:5
```

WP version 5.1, WooCommerce version 3.5.5, Advanced AJAX Product Filters version 1.3.0.2., Local server.

Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

you need to update the Scrollbar.concat.min.js file for this. Before editing, you should beautify it using an online tool.

After that, search for - e(t).load(function() and replace it with e(t).on( 'load', function()

After this, you should again minify the js file using the online tool and save the changes.

You should disable plugin updates otherwise your changes will be lost.

This should fix the issue.

Let me know if this works for you.